# What is the "Was this post useful?" thing for?

Tags: support, user-interface

When I am logged out and I browse a random post I see this:

[image]

Note the little question below.  What is that for?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is for anonymous users to vote on the quality of a post.

It gathers opinions from people with no account or little rep in a way that doesn't affect the user or the poster's reputation.

**Source: [Anonymous user feedback now in testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing)**

Comment: I always thought those were ignored by the guys over at SE.  Thanks for the answer and the link!

Comment: 10k+ users can see these, I use it to edit/improve high traffic questions.

Answer (score 1):

That is an option for unregistered users to express their feedback regarding the quality of a post.

It also does not affect the votes of the post.